# Example of a function that lies inside the Hardy space $H^1$ but not in the Hardy space $H^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

I know examples of $H^\infty$ and $H^2$ functions. So can anyone give me an example of $H^2$ function whose square is not inside $H^2$? Thanks . . .

Comment: Will you please make it clear how it belongs to $H^1$ but does not belong to $H^2$? Thanks in advance . .  .

Comment: I meant $(1+z)^{-2/3}$ then. It is obvious why

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!